# Lightbox not working in my website

Tags: html

I am trying to integrate lightbox on my website, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I know that I have my `css` and `js` files correct because when I copy the `index.html` file it works, but when I try to use my own it doesn't for some reason.

**Please excuse the music and the cheesyness of this website**
Here is the website [link][1]

It's the first 4 images. I copied exactly from the example?
Here is my `index.html` file this is for the gallery section only.

```
<article id="gallery" class="panel">
    <header>
        <center>
            <h2>Gallery</h2>
        </center>
        <div class="image-row">
            <div class="image-set"> 
                <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-row">
        ...
```

Comment: Take a look at the browser console. 3 images are missing. I don't know if that's the problem, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Also, you're loading jQuery twice. That can break things, too.

Comment: which jQuery am I loading twice? and I see the images?

Comment: I'm loading only 5 script tags, but they are all different

Comment: Did you look at the console like I suggested? You get 3 404 errors on images.

Comment: `js/jquery.min.js` and `js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js` are the same thing.

Comment: Pretty sure that isn't the issue. Are you looking at `firebug?`

Comment: Chrome dev tools, and doubling up on jQuery causes all sorts of problems.

Comment: im like 100% that isn't the problem nor the missing images

Comment: I'm 100% sure your approach to debugging isn't sound. I'll be happy to help further when I see only one jQuery loaded in the page.

Comment: okay I listened to your advice and deleted `js/jquery.min.js` although I believe the two files are different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71367/discussion-between-isherwood-and-krukusa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loading the Lightbox CSS. Add this to your page head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css"></link>
```

And there may be image files or other assets also needed to get Lightbox looking right.

Also, remove one of the two jQuery calls. Even if it doesn't break things (which is rare), you don't want your visitors to have to download two big library files for no reason.